# Pocketsphinx decoder fails to initialize

Tags: android, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I am trying to implement a hotword in my app which will start the speech input using CMUSphinx. I copied the code from the tutorial, did some changes to start the speech input but it is not working. My mainActivity code for the recognition looks something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (PrefManager.getString(Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN, null) == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not signed in, Cannot access resource!");
    }
    clientBuilder = new ClientBuilder();
    init();
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
        return;
    }
    runRecognizerSetup();
}
private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";

private void runRecognizerSetup() {
    // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
    // so we execute it in async task
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Assets assets = new Assets(MainActivity.this);
                File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                setupRecognizer(assetDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed",LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            runRecognizerSetup();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
 * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
 * for final result in onResult.
 */
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis == null)
        return;

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE))
        promptSpeechInput();
}

/**
 * This callback is called when we stop the recognizer.
 */
@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis){
    if (hypothesis != null) {
        String pqr = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pqr,LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
}

/**
 * We stop recognizer here to get a final result
 */
@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    if (!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(KWS_SEARCH))
        switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}

private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
    recognizer.stop();

    // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
    if (searchName.equals(KWS_SEARCH))
        recognizer.startListening(searchName);
    else
        recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);
}

private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
    // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
    // of different kind and switch between them

    recognizer = SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))

            .setRawLogDir(assetsDir) // To disable logging of raw audio comment out this call (takes a lot of space on the device)

            .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);

    /** In your application you might not need to add all those searches.
     * They are added here for demonstration. You can leave just one.
     */

    // Create keyword-activation search.
    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);


       }

@Override
public void onError(Exception error) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onTimeout() {
    switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
}
```

My keyphrase is "HI". The problem is that whenever I run this code I get a toast message "failed" due to this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed",LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

What can be possibly wrong with this?

I am very new to these things so any help in this will be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: You can find additional details in logcat